# WPF desktop client application authentication with Microsoft, Google against Account Azure API service

Tags: api, azure, authentication, desktop

I need to support three forms of authentication in my Azure API service: custom, Microsoft Account, and Google account.  The service is set up to support these.  The UWP client code seems to work.  However, I need to perform the same authentication process using a Winforms or WPF (full desktop) application.  The Azure mobile libraries do not seem to be the same for these platforms.   How does one get this to work?